# Login loop after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: login, 22.04

I followed this guide to upgrade the os to the most recent LTS.

https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-to-ubuntu-22-04

Everything finished without errors, but when I went to log in to the GUI it just kicks back to the login. I can log into a terminal session. I tried checking file permissions in ~ and /tmp per some suggestions and everything was as it should be. I even removed and re-installed gnome per https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop-issue/. Does anyone else have any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?